# Angular: Reset Array without reloading view in Ui

Tags: angular, typescript

I currently have the following code for the html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let goal of goalList;>
  <tab>
    <h3 class="...">{{goal?.title}}</h3>
    <p class="...">{{goal?.description}}</p>
  </tab>
</ng-container>
```

I need to have empty 'goal' objects, that the ngFor for the tabs works. So in the component I initialize the goalList Array like this: `this.goalList = Array(goalCount) // as I know the count already`.

Later, once requested I will load the goalList from backend with Observable and replace the 'empty' Array with the result from the server:

```
this.serviceExample.goalListObservable.subscribe(
  data => this.goalList = data
));
```

Unfortunately at this moment, the current values will disappear, as the array behind get overwritten.

Is it possible to change the array in the component that the values in the Ui are getting refreshed automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create another array and save the answer from the observable in this array.

```
this.serviceExample.goalListObservable.subscribe(
  data => this.newArray = data
));
```

And in the frontent you use the array you had already for the ngFor, and the data you take from the second array:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let goal of goalList; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
  <tab>
    <ng-container *ngIf="newArray">
      <h3 class="...">{{newArray[i]?.title}}</h3>
      <p class="...">{{newArray[i]?.description}}</p>
    </ng-container>
  </tab>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Works great!! Thank you :)